# UPS Shipping AND Default shipping plugin options

Tags: expresso-store, shipping, ups-shipping

With the old version of store, we had UPS figured options and a flat rate international option, but with the latest version and the UPS plugin, only the UPS options appear. Is it not possible to have both? And how do we apply Free shipping to the UPS options with discounts?

No problem! The latest version of store that we have is 2.5.1, we are upgrading from 1.6.5. We have the code in the last stage of our checkout & it only displays the UPS options:

```
<tr>        
    <th colspan="2" class="input-styles" style="padding-top: 5px; border-bottom: 0;">
        <span class="checkout-labels">Shipping:</span><select name="shipping_method" id="shipping_method" style="display: inline-block; width: 139px; font-size: 10px !important;">
            <option value="">Select shipping method...</option>
                {shipping_method_options}
        </select>
    </th>
    <th class="input-styles" id="js-shipping-price" style="text-align: right; vertical-align: top; padding: 5px 10px 0 0; border-bottom: 0;">
        {order_shipping}
    </th>
</tr>
```

Comment: You can still have both UPS and the default shipping gateways enabled and used. We will need a bit more information and probably some template code form your checkout templates to be able to fully help you. Such as what version of Store you are using now and what the "old version" was.

Comment: No problem! The latest version of store that we have is 2.5.1, we are upgrading from 1.6.5

Comment: edited to show more info requested and sample code.

Comment: In Store 2 the shipping options will only show if they are eligible for that delivery address for example if you have a default shipping gateway option for Canada and the user enters a shipping address in The US it will not show up as an option for the user to select but you will see options for UPS if that gateway is setup to ship to the US.

Comment: That makes sense! How do I go about offering free shipping then for UPS rates and only on UPS ground?

Comment: In Store 2 the promotions are broken up into 2 sections now. Sales change the product price before it is in the users cart. Discounts (think promo codes) are applied during checkout. If you are using a discount you would simply need to select the "Free Shipping" box when you create the discount. I have not used the UPS gateway in Store 2 so I can't speak for sure but I believe the user would still be able to select a different shipping speed from the select field. If you needed to limit it to only an option you could use a conditional to check if the promo code causes free

Comment: shipping and then preselect the UPS ground option`{if discount:free_shipping}<input type="hidden" name="shipping_method" value="X_shipping_id">{/if}` this will force the cart to use UPS ground

Comment: Ok, one more question, can I set that up so it works for free shipping without a promo code? So for example, this weekend, everyone gets free shipping?

Comment: Short answer is not out of the box. You would need to to create an extension that would make shipping free based upon X and Y rules.  or some form of template logic to assign a promo code based on certain criteria.

Comment: I'm really close on this, but cannot seem to get past having only Ground shipping be free, while still allowing users to pay for the other options. I tried adding a default rule called free ground shipping and pulling a conditional checking the discount note, so it wouldn't trigger the Free options for the UPS methods, but this did not work, and the Free option also always appaers. 

Any ASAP help here would be much appreciated.